# Selecting d3 node from within child context (e.g. a timer)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to know the simplest way to select a d3 node from within a child context like a timer - for example...

```
var nodeEnter = node
                .enter()           
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .on("mousedown", function(d) { 

                    //d3.select(this) returns the node here (SVGGElement)

                    pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() { 
                        //d3.select(this, d3.select(this.parent), d3.select(this).parent return [object Window] here
```

Since I can't seem to rely on d3.select(this) from within the timer, if I want to update a property of the node there, then I have to first change the data  and then update all the nodes with a selectAll(.node) statement, for example...

```
d.node_ring_width = 12;

node.selectAll(".outlinecircle").attr("stroke-width", function(d) { 
                                        return d.node_ring_width; 
});
```

Does anyone know of a better way to pull the parent context and enable me to access the node directly?  Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the value of `this` by using a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). You will then be able to access the original value of `this` within the callback supplied to `.setTimeout()`.

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter()           
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .on("mousedown", function(d) { 

                        var self = this;  // Save the reference to this

                        pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() { 
                            // self contains the saved reference
                            d3.select(self);
                            d3.select(self.parentNode);
                        }, 1000);
                    });
```

Comment: thank you - that'll do nicely - don't know why it didn't occur to me sorry!